# Error when getting Sesssion Id for community user using SOAP UI

Tags: customer-portal, session

When iam getting Session Id for customer Community user through Soap UI, getting the following error.

```
  "SERVER_UNAVAILABLE: internal server error (20228)"
```

Can any one tell me where is the problem and how can i solve this issue & get session Id.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add your code please and complete the question ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how your typical request should look like in SOAP UI :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:login>
         <urn:username>replacerwitheuserid</urn:username>
         <urn:password>replacewithpasswordreplacewithsecuritytoken</urn:password>
      </urn:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now if your request structure is correct and still you get the same error message, I would go ahead and check trust.salesforce.com to see if server is down for maintainence and also check the Login IP restriction against the profile of User im loggin in through.

Comment: Amit, I have checked trust.salesforce.com and Login IP restriction,there is no IP restriction for that profile user but still iam getting the same issue.

Comment: Were you able to login before and this problem arises now or this the first time you are trying through community user?

Comment: yes, i was able to login before but now this problem arises. so that i have created new Community user and try to login first time then also iam getting same issue..

Comment: Can you paste your login code in your question ?